# Best way to go about replacing forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make an application where the users can click on the buttons to navigate through different forms. I.E: If I click on network status, it replaces the Main Form with a network status form, and then you can go back to the main form by clicking on "return".

What would be the best approach to do this? I'm thinking panels but people told me to use usercontrol and I'm not quite familiar with it. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I'm guessing you're wanting to achieve something similar to the Windows 7 navigation forms, like so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87738/C-Windows-Aero-Style-Wizard-Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hi,

Assuming your requirement as depicted in the `storyboard`. Have a `UserControl of these many controls` which are `DOCKED` as per the picture on the UserControl. Now in the blank area you will have to `show / hide` your `page / form / screen`.

I would suggest this piece of code can do the trick for you to display / hide form dynamically on navigation. Have this in your navigation bit i.e. Next / Prev click on the `Usercontrol` -

```
        form.Location = new Point(leftPaneControl.Width , BannerControl.Height);
        form.Size = new Size(this.Width - leftPaneControl.Width, this.Height - BannerControl.Height);
        form.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left |
                                   AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.Controls.Add(form);
```

On Next and Prev clicks , you just do `Controls.RemoveByKey(...)` to hide the existing form & the above code will `add` the next respective form after you have instantiated the same. This is a pretty cool function to remove control[s] from a collection if you have defined `unique names` for all your `forms / screen / page` [whatever you say].

> This approach / design will allow you to just focus on designing your
>   pages / screens because creating this Usercontrol is a one-time
>   activity. After that you will only design your individual navigation pages / screens one by
>   one.

Answer (score 2):

Looking on the post don't see *any* reason for non having just another `Form`.

Why do not just create another, fully functional `Form`, and hide "source" `Form`.

Can create some, sort of `forms linked list` structure, where you have (say)

```
public class MyAppForm : Form 
{
     MyAppForm _prev... 
     MyAppForm _next...
}
```

In this way where (say) `Go to next` button clicked, we hide original, pick and show `_next`.

Just an idea. You may change it in a way to make it simplier or fit better your app needs.

Comment: Well I kinda don't like the fact that it repositions the window (or even resizes) when a new form is made. I'd like to keep it with respect to the previous form.

Comment: @it's true, with `user control`, or some hidden `panel`, it's easier to achieve. But position and resize new `Form` in right way is not a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

You could use several forms where ever needed and `Show` and `Hide` them as required.

You might also consider using something like MDI forms, where you can have one parent form that could host your menus, status and other bars.